# Hadoop - Issues setting up single node cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, tcp

Im trying to setup a Hadoop single node cluster following this article -

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

Everthing looks good but when start the hadoop and list all the ports I see few are missing.

These are the ports in my machine.
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       50434       5765/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       45587       5461/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       45594       5461/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8030            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       47365       5765/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       47353       5765/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8032            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       47373       5765/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       50861       5765/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40641           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       50843       5885/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       46697       5461/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8040            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       50850       5885/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       50854       5885/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       46221       5610/java

and this the list from the link.

hduser@laptop:~$ netstat -plten | grep java
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1843372     10605/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1841277     10447/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1841130     10895/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1840196     10447/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1841320     10605/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       1841646     10605/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1845543     11383/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1845551     11383/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1842110     11252/java
tcp6       0      0 :::49630                :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1845534     11383/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8030                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1842036     11252/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8031                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1842005     11252/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8032                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1842100     11252/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8033                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       1842162     11252/java

Few important things that I miss is 50070 which is used for the web portal.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which Hadoop processes are running using `jps` command.

This  will show you the process names like NameNode, ResourceManager etc. preceded by their process Id.
eg:

```
7413 Jps
38754 ResourceManager
37054 NameNode
37338 SecondaryNameNode
```

This tells you that the Namenode and the Resource manager are alive.
You can then use `netstat` to check which ports these processes are using. eg:

```
netstat -lnptu |grep 37054
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      37054/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50070        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      37054/java
```

The ports can be changed by setting the appropriate configuration parameter in the correct configuration file.